# Two buttons problems

Tags: javascript, html, button

I'm writing a code for a class that should convert a number into Celsius or Fahrenheit (a really primitive code). I built the basics, and it seems to work. However, when I try to click on the lower button it won't produce an output unless the first one is clicked. Would love some help on how to fix that.

Thank you again!

```js
function temperatureF() {
  let x = document.getElementById('value').value;
  let result = (9 / 5 * x) + 32;
  return result;
}

function temperatureC() {
  let y = document.getElementById('value').value;
  let result = (y - 32) * 5 / 9;
  return result;
}


$("#theButton1").click(function() {
  let theNumber = temperatureF;
  $('#output1').html(theNumber);
  $("output1").addClass("alert alert-success");

  $("#theButton2").click(function() {
    let theNumber = temperatureC;
    $('#output2').html(theNumber);
    $("output2").addClass("alert alert-success");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 border border-primary">
      <h1>Conversions</h1>
      <form>
        <label for="value">Enter your value:      </label>
        <input type="number" id="value" name="input">
      </form>
      <br>
      <form>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="theButton1" value="Press for Farenheit">
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="output1" style="font-size:2em;">
      </div>
      <form>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="theButton2" value="Press for Celsius">
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="output2" style="font-size:2em;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have your second click handler inside the first click handler. They should both be at top-level.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you accidentally placed the code setting up the event listener for the second button *inside* the event listener for the first button.  Here it is below fixed:

```js
function temperatureF() {
  let x = document.getElementById('value').value;
  let result = (9 / 5 * x) + 32;
  return result;
}

function temperatureC() {
  let y = document.getElementById('value').value;
  let result = (y - 32) * 5 / 9;
  return result;
}


$("#theButton1").click(function() {
  let theNumber = temperatureF;
  $('#output1').html(theNumber);
  $("output1").addClass("alert alert-success");
});

$("#theButton2").click(function() {
  let theNumber = temperatureC;
  $('#output2').html(theNumber);
  $("output2").addClass("alert alert-success");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4 border border-primary">
      <h1>Conversions</h1>
      <form>
        <label for="value">Enter your value:      </label>
        <input type="number" id="value" name="input">
      </form>
      <br>
      <form>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="theButton1" value="Press for Farenheit">
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="output1" style="font-size:2em;">
      </div>
      <form>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="theButton2" value="Press for Celsius">
      </form>
      <br>
      <div id="output2" style="font-size:2em;">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      &nbsp;
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Also, as [user Raptor noted in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68992039/two-buttons-problems/68992052?noredirect=1#comment121933793_68992052), you can sometimes run into issues when mixing vanilla JS and jQuery; you'll have an easier time debugging if you run all your DOM querying through jQuery.

Comment: I was wondering why this works even though he left off the `()` after `temperatureF` and `temperatureC`. It's because jQuery `.html()` allows you to give a function instead of a string -- it calls the function to get the string. This is usually used as a shortcut instead of using `.each()`. The OP probably didn't intend it here.

Comment: Thank you so much! I always mess up when it comes to the brackets.

Comment: @Barmar - interesting callout-- I must admit I didn't catch that when answering. I haven't used jQuery professionally in years, but it is still full of interesting little surprises like this.

Comment: for better practice, don't mix vanilla JS with jQuery, e.g. change `document.getElementById('value').value` to `$('#value').val()`.

Comment: @Raptor - good point; I usually mention that but forgot this time around.  I have updated the question with this callout.